# Issue in adding dynamic scope variable in ng-src

Tags: angularjs

I want a append a dynamic variable that is my host name to image url but I add that I am getting error in console. I used the below code.
In controller.

```
$scope.host ="localhost:8199/";
<img ng-src="{{group.groupImagePath ?"+host+"group.groupImagePath :    ('img/group.png')}}"/>
```

I want to get the host

Comment: What's the error and what's the controller?

Comment: http://localhost:8080//%7B%7Bgroup.groupImagePath%20? 404 (Not Found)

Comment: is host ur baseUrl variable? and is it scope element?

Comment: yes its naseurl variable and in fact it's a scope element

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better if you keep your view cleaner and construct the final url inside your controller only:

```
$scope.url = $scope.group.groupImagePath ? $scope.host +  $scope.group.groupImagePath : 'img/group.png';
```

Then inside your view,

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}"/>
```

Comment: I have a list of element actually.

Comment: @Karthik Are you using this inside an `ng-repeat` ?